# How to apply XML Namespaces

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to parse some xml from a SOAP API. I am quite new to XML, but i can get it to work when i only have the body of the statement. I have tried applying some simple namespaces, but I am not sure whether this is the right path to pursue.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Account_GetDataArrayResponse xmlns="http://e-conomic.com">
            <Account_GetDataArrayResult>
                <AccountData>
                    <Handle>
                        <Number>1000</Number>
                    </Handle>
                    <Number>1000</Number>
                    <Name>RESULTATOPGØRELSE</Name>
                    <Type>Heading</Type>
                    <DebitCredit>Debit</DebitCredit>
                    <IsAccessible>true</IsAccessible>
                    <BlockDirectEntries>false</BlockDirectEntries>
                    <Balance>0.00</Balance>
                </AccountData>
                <AccountData>
                    <Handle>
                        <Number>1001</Number>
                    </Handle>
                    <Number>1001</Number>
                    <Name>Omsætning</Name>
                    <Type>Heading</Type>
                    <DebitCredit>Debit</DebitCredit>
                    <IsAccessible>true</IsAccessible>
                    <BlockDirectEntries>false</BlockDirectEntries>
                    <Balance>0.00</Balance>
                </AccountData>
            </Account_GetDataArrayResult>
        </Account_GetDataArrayResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS e) 


SELECT
    AccountHandleNumber = AccountData.value('(Handle/Number)[1]', 'int')
    ,AccountName = AccountData.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
    ,AccountNumber = AccountData.value('(Number)[1]', 'int')
    ,AccountType = AccountData.value('(Type)[1]','varchar(20)')
    ,AccountDebitCredit = AccountData.value('(DebitCredit)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
    ,AccountIsAccessible = AccountData.value('(IsAccessible)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
    ,AccountBlockDirectEntries = AccountData.value('(BlockDirectEntries)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
    ,AccountBalance = AccountData.value('(Balance)[1]', 'float')
FROM  @XMLFile.nodes('/Account_GetDataArrayResponse/Account_GetDataArrayResult/AccountData') AS XTbl(AccountData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is **very much** the right way!

However, you're not reading the entire XML you have - you have to really start at the root node - so try to adapt your code like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS e, 
                    DEFAULT 'http://e-conomic.com') 
SELECT
    AccountHandleNumber = AccountData.value('(Handle/Number)[1]', 'int')
    ..... 
FROM  
    @XMLFile.nodes('/e:Envelope/e:Body/Account_GetDataArrayResponse/Account_GetDataArrayResult/AccountData') AS XTbl(AccountData)
```

First of all - you need to also take care of the `<soap:Envelope>` and `<soap:Body>` tags at the very beginning of the document - you've created a XML namespace alias of `e` for that - so you need to include `/e:Envelope/e:Body` at the beginning of your XPath expression in the `.nodes()` call.

Also: the `<Account_GetDataArrayResponse>` node declares another XML namespace which gets applied throughout the rest of the XML document - I've added that as the `DEFAULT` XML namespace to the query, so it will be applied to any node in the XPath expression that doesn't have an explicit XML namespace prefix associated with it

Comment: Thanks a lot, that cleared up quite a few questions for me.

Still, there seems to be something not working as I do not get any records returned. The query does execute but returns nothing. Am I using the right Namespace, there are three, but I guess I am to use the xmlns:?

Any help is appreciated.

Rasmus

Comment: @RasmusRødbyKristiansen: ah yes - you used the *wrong* XML namespace in your `WITH XMLNAMESPACES....` header; you need to use the one that's associated with the `soap` prefix in the original XML document. Try my updated response

Comment: Great, Thanks a bunch! 

I surely need to read up on all of this, as I see that its working, but not really understanding why. Have a lovely day.. @marc_s

Comment: First time... Not last! Thanks again